# parameterized doctype in xsl:stylesheet

Tags: xml, docbook, xslt

How could I inject a --stringparam (xsltproc) into the DOCTYPE of a XSL stylesheet? The --stringparam is specified from the command line.

I have several books in docbook5 format I want to process with the same customization layer, each book having an unique identifier, here "demo", so I'm running something like

> xsltproc --stringparam course.name demo ...

for each book.

Obviously the parameter is not recognized as such, but as verbatim text, giving the error:

> warning: failed to load external entity "http://edu.yet-another-project.com/course/$(course.name)/entities.ent"

Here it is how I've tried, which won't work:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY % myent SYSTEM "http://edu.yet-another-project.com/course/$(course.name)/entities.ent">
%myent;
]>
<xsl:stylesheet  
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">

<!-- the docbook template used -->
<xsl:import href="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook/xhtml/chunk.xsl"/>

<!-- processor parameters -->
<xsl:param name="html.stylesheet">default.css</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="use.id.as.filename">1</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="chunker.output.encoding">UTF-8</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="chunker.output.indent">yes</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="navig.graphics">1</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="generate.revhistory.link">1</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="admon.graphics">1</xsl:param>

<!-- here more stuff -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ideas?

Comment: Please, specify what is exactly the output you wnat produced.

Comment: I want the entity file `http://edu.yet-another-project.com/course/demo/entities.ent` to be processed. It works if I use the literal "demo" (I'm using an xml catalog file to map the URIs).

Comment: Ok, generally: I am processing multiple books with the same customization layer. Each book has an unique name. 1. I need this unique name inside the stylesheet. 2. I need to include book-specific entities which are always inside a fixed file named `entities.ent` inside the directory where the currently processed book has its source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output

> ```
> <xsl:output
>   method = "xml" | "html" | "text" | qname-but-not-ncname 
>   version = nmtoken 
>   encoding = string 
>   omit-xml-declaration = "yes" | "no"
>   standalone = "yes" | "no"
>   doctype-public = string 
>   doctype-system = string 
>   cdata-section-elements = qnames 
>   indent = "yes" | "no"
>   media-type = string />
> ```

So, when using XSLT 1.0 you can't parameterize public nor system DOCTYPE strings.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document

> ```
> <xsl:result-document
>   format? = { qname }
>   href? = { uri-reference }
>   validation? = "strict" | "lax" | "preserve" | "strip"
>   type? = qname
>   method? = { "xml" | "html" | "xhtml" | "text" |
>   qname-but-not-ncname }
>   byte-order-mark? = { "yes" | "no" }
>   cdata-section-elements? = { qnames }
>   doctype-public? = { string }
>   doctype-system? = { string }
>   encoding? = { string }
>   escape-uri-attributes? = { "yes" | "no" }
>   include-content-type? = { "yes" | "no" }
>   indent? = { "yes" | "no" }
>   media-type? = { string }
>   normalization-form? = { "NFC" | "NFD" | "NFKC" | "NFKD" |
>   "fully-normalized" | "none" | nmtoken }
>   omit-xml-declaration? = { "yes" | "no" }
>   standalone? = { "yes" | "no" | "omit" }
>   undeclare-prefixes? = { "yes" | "no" }
>   use-character-maps? = qnames
>   output-version? = { nmtoken }>
>   <!-- Content: sequence-constructor -->
> </xsl:result-document>
> ```

In XSLT 2.0 you can use `xsl:result-document` instruction for that task.

Comment: Could you show an example .xsl and .dtd file which does it in xslt 2.0?

Comment: This answer mentions some options that can be used to customize the output resulting from an XSLT transformation. But it is not an answer to the original question, which is about parameterizing the DOCTYPE in the stylesheet itself.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, as long as I get my book-specific entities injected into the global stylesheet - I can restructure the files if that's needed in order to get the desired result. But I've tried what he has suggested and I couldn't manage to do it (and remember, it has to use the parameter `course.name`). That's why I'd like to see a working example.

Comment: @Flavius: DTD is not part of the Infoset nor XDM (besides the fact that some data could be aviable). So, if you want to extend an specific DOCTYPE declaration with parameterized entities, you have to go with DOE. Other solution is to have parameterized DOCTYPE (with static system resurces), wich is posible in XSLT 2.0

Comment: @Flavius, how about creating a new question (as you have already mentioned yourself)? This one has been answered, and what Alejandro suggests will not help in getting your entities "injected into the global stylesheet".

Comment: @Alejandro: yep, I'll most probably go with xslt 2.0, you've mentioned it in your answer, but wouldn't be nice to also show a simple example, not longer than 20 lines or so? Copy/pasting from the spec doesn't really help.

Comment: @Flavius: Yes. Please, provide a small input sample and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The `course.name` parameter is given to the **XSLT processor**. But it is the **XML parser** that sees the entity declaration containing `$(course.name)`, and the parser won't know what to do with that. The entity cannot be expanded.

You need to declare `course.name` as a parameter in the stylesheet and then reference it somewhere in a custom template.

Comment: It's the stylesheet (my customization layer `online-course.xsl` where I need some entities from `http://edu.yet-another-project.com/course/demo/entities.ent`. This customization layer will get course.name from the command line, yes, that's no problem. The problem is how to get to the entities from within this stylesheet in a context-aware manner, based on course.name (that is, course.name puts my customization layer "online-course.xsl" in the the "context" of the "demo" book.

Comment: If you want to use entities declared in `entities.ent` in your stylesheet, that's perfectly fine. But you cannot parameterize the path or URL to this file; it must be fixed and literal. Your question was: "How could I inject a --stringparam (xsltproc) into the DOCTYPE of a XSL stylesheet?". The answer is: "It is not possible".

Comment: Ok, so shall I create a new question now, asking for a strategy to accomplish my task?